# Javascript problem in sum using process.argv

Tags: javascript, sum, argv

I'm trying to make a simple operation in js. This is my code:

```
var propriedade = process.argv[2]; 
var a = process.argv[3]; 
var b = process.argv[4];
var result = 0;
switch(propriedade) {
  case "sum":
    result = a + b;
    break;
  case "minus":
    result = a - b;
    break;
} 
console.log(result);
```

In the terminal the result not is not the sum. What's wrong?

Comment: Please supply the command you were running (which args did you pass and what is the printed result)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Next time, please explain the result you have got.

In fact, when you used the `process.argv[i]`, the result you get is a string:

```
console.log(
  {
      typeA: typeof a,
      typeB: typeof b
  }
);
```

**OUTPUT**

```js
{
   typeA: 'string',
   typeB: 'string'
}
```

As you know **String** + **String** is concatenation so if you pass for exemple "12" and "45" it will return "1245" and not 57.

For that, you should use the following method to convert string to a number (it works for integer or float):

```js
let a = Number(process.argv[3]);
let b = Number(process.argv[4]);
```

Now it works very well !!!

**[EDIT]**

In javascript, if you are using operators like "*", "/" or "-" for example (except "+"), string are converted to Numbers.

```js
let a = "5";
let b = "2"; 
console.log({
    sum: a + b,
    minus: a - b,
    multiplication: a * b,
    devide: a / b
});
//OUTPUT: { sum: '52', minus: 3, multiplication: 10, devide: 2.5 }
```

Comment: hello, sorry for not explaing my result wish. But you resolve my problem, before in the sum the terminal read how Strings. What was strange was only in the sum